# How do I align the NAV to the right side of the page?

Tags: html, css, header

I am having an issue with my header on my website.

When I try to float the logo to the left, and float the nav to the right at the same time, it pushes all the content down and the 'header' joins the 'section' tag.

This is the JSFiddle if you would like to play around with it, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/wh7wdpmu/

```
#logo {
    width: 125px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
nav {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

(Above is the CSS for the logo and nav so far)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the logo to the far left and the menu to the far right?

If so you can try this: [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/wh7wdpmu/8/)

I added the floats `left` and `right` for the `logo` and `nav` respectively. I then added `width: 100%` to your `header` as well as an `inline-block` display property. Remove the excessive `img` margin to the logo (or add it to the `header` instead).

```
body {
    background-image:url("http://i300.photobucket.com/albums/nn18/ojijimanuel/LONDONWALLPAPERBLUR_zpstm3nxnwu.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-right:100px;
}
#logo {
    width:125px;
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
}
header {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
}
section h1 {
    color:white;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:50px; 
}
section {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:300px;
}
#learnmore {
    border:none;
    background-color:#191919;
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-right:30px;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    color:white;
    float:left;
    opacity:0.5;
    margin-top:100px;
}
#learnmore:hover {
    opacity:1.0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#learnmore a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}
p {
    color:white;
    font-family:arial;
}
nav {
    display:inline-block;
    float: right;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#cccccc;
    font-family:arial;
    padding-right:20px;
    font-size:15px;
}
nav a:hover {
    color:white;
}
```

Also, you have an extra `<nav>` tag in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the float on your header. Try applying `overflow: hidden;` on your header.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wh7wdpmu/)

(You also had an extra `nav` tag in there)